# Permission issue when publish comment with Facebook Graph API v2.12

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I am testing the facebook graph API comments
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/comments

1. I checked my permission for the access token it contains the permission, which required by API. see the screenshot

[image]

2. I test my object-id (1797963943566411_1975256375837166)  which is correct see me screenshot

[image]

3. Change the request method to POST and adding post data `{"message": "haha"}`
   I get the error message shows:
   "(#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens" see my screenshot

[image]

As you can see the first step checking, I have all the permission that the 
API required.

Can any one see any sort of error in this process?

Comment: Do you have a page access token? For the page that you are commenting on?

Comment: Forget to mention, the facebook user that I used for API test is my App tester user. (I assigned the tester role to this user). My App permission have not been officially reviewed by Facebook. Not sure it is the issue. If this is a issue, how can we test API before getting review.

Comment: @WizKid I did not put any page access token when I use facebook Graph API explore. How to use this page access token with Graph API explore. I can get this token by call /me/accounts but not sure how to use it.

Comment: You can read about page access tokens on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens

Comment: @WizKid  My post is on my timeline is not facebook page. So API changed. no longer supporting comments on the facebook timeline post. It is really sad to prevent this .  The documentation super unclear. did not mention anything where to use this API for comments.

Comment: Seems like the error message is super clear

Answer (score 0):

Try another way still not work.

I have a user who post a photo on his own facebook page.

1. I logged in with this user and give this user all permissions see the screenshot
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFTSC.png)
2. call /me/accounts to get page access token
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puYQ5.png)
3. copy the page access token into the Graph API Explorer's access token field
   call 
   `GET: 1797963943566411_1975256375837166/likes`
   is working fine

But call `POST: 1797963943566411_1975256375837166/likes`

Get error response:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "GtEaBfyXrUD"
  }
}`

The reason is Facebook changed the API behaviour. We are no longer to use api to like any POST on our time line. API can only like or comments on  facebook page. Sad face !!!!